# Can I use MDM servers to manage Ad-Hoc iOS applications?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, deployment

We are investigating the possibility to manage iOS devices with MDM server. 
We are also planning to joint iOS Developer Enterprise Program in near future.
Fot for now we are using Ad-Hoc provisioning.
Is it possible to use Ad-Hoc with MDM ?
For example we need to set up trial MDM servers to understand what approach is better but do we need Enterprise program for that ? The documentation says about Enterprise in-house and AppStore but nothing about Ad-Hoc distribution (to manage for example these 100 allowed devices)
Thanks in advance
Victor